# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i having this problem in eclipse

I m running a simple project and following error appears:

```
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

after this a dialog box appears showing "Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start." I have searched and tried all options answered here and nothing work for me. I also searched ports and change the tomcat port but nothing helps.? what should i do?

First i was getting the error "Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

after changing port,i am getting "Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start" error..

Answer (score 1):

The errormessage sounds very clear - that port (8005) is already in use. Are you running two instances of tomcat in parallel? Maybe one from command line and one from eclipse?

Comment: i have changed the ports HTTP/1.1  and AJP/1.3 and the error "Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start" appear now

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error message?

Comment: I have changed Tomcat admin port to 8006, HTTP/1.1 to 8086 and AJP/1.3 to 8005 and this works for now, thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because of `8005` port is using by some other application.

so change the port number in eclipse by

1. Double click on Apache Tomcat Server in server tab and open the server in eclipse
2. expand port panel
3. change `HTTP/1.1`, `tomcat admin port` and `AJP/1.3`(check used port by typing `netstat -an` in `cmd`)
4. save it

try again

Comment: ,I have changed Tomcat admin port to 8006, HTTP/1.1 to 8086 and AJP/1.3 to 8005 and this works for now, thanks for pointing out the error